# How do you count the edges of each connected component of an undirected graph with depth-first search?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

Given numbers k and h for an undirected graph, check with dfs if any of the connected components has more than k edges and if we have more than h connected components. Return false if one of this cases is true. Is my solution correct ?
Note that for this exercise I don't need predecessor and time variables but I have left them for clarity. My main concern is the count variable.

```
    DFS(G)
    for each vertex u in G.V
        u.color = WHITE
        u.predecessor = NIL
    time = 0
    n = 0; //counts connected components
    for each vertex u in G.V
       if u.color == WHITE
            n = n + 1
            count = 0  // assign 0 initially for every connected component
            DFS-VISIT(G,U)
            if ((count + |Adj[u]|)/2 > k) 
                    return false;
    if (n > h) 
           return false;



   DFS-VISIT(G,u)
    time = time + 1 // white vertex u has just been discovered
    u.d = time      //u discovery time
    u.color = GRAY
    for each v in G.Adj[u]  // explore edge (u,v) 
         if v.color == WHITE
              count = count + |Adj[v]| //all edges are white only once.Sum of all adj lists for every vertice  gives 2|E|                       
              v.predecessor = u
              DFS-VISIT(G,v)
    u.color = BLACK // blacken u; it is finished
    time = time + 1
    u.f = time      //u finishing time
```

Comment: what is your question? your algo looks correct.

Comment: If it is correct ?! Especially the count variable.

Comment: It is correct :) Please go to [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want to review your code

Answer (score 0):

I think following will do

Initially `col[]` initialised with 1 and 2->Not yet finished and 0->Finished

```
void dfs(long int i,list<long int> *edge,bool visited[],int col[],long int par[]){
    visited[i]=true;
    col[i]=2;
    list<long int>::iterator k;
    for(k=edge[i].begin();k!=edge[i].end();k++){
        int u=*k;
        if(col[u]==1){
            par[u]=i;
            e++;
            dfs(u,edge,visited,col,par);
        }
        else if(col[u]==2&&u!=par[i])
            e++;
    }
    col[i]=0;
}
```